# WPF Access control inside ContentControl

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, contentcontrol

I am having a very hard time trying to access my Grid (listBoxGrid) from inside the ContentControl from code behind.  Any help or pointers would be great!

Thanks
Ryan

```
    <Style x:Key="ccTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <Grid x:Name="listBoxGrid" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="200*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="6" >
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type control:ListBoxControl}" TargetType="{x:Type control:ListBoxControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ccTemplate}" x:Name="cc">
                    <telerikNavigation:RadTreeView 
    Name="mainList"
    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ItemsSource}" 
                            ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MainDataTemplate}"
                            ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MainStyle}"
    MinWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=MinWidth}" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    BorderBrush="#FF00569F"
                            Background="{DynamicResource ListItemBackground}"
    BorderThickness="1"
                            SelectionMode="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectionMode, FallbackValue=Single}"
                            IsDragDropEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsDragDropEnabled, FallbackValue=False}"
                            IsDropPreviewLineEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsDropPreviewLineEnabled, FallbackValue=True}"
                            AllowDrop="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=AllowDrop, FallbackValue=True}"
    >
                    </telerikNavigation:RadTreeView>
                </ContentControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I have tried

```
Grid myGrid = (Grid)Template.FindName("listBoxGrid", this);
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can only access template parts in the OnApplyTemplate() method override using GetTemplateChild("PartName").

Comment: In the OnApplyTemplate override, I tried Grid myGrid = GetTemplateChild("listBoxGrid") as Grid;  and still myGrid is null.

Comment: Actually just found out that what I wrote strictly applies to Silverlight only, in WPF you should be able to use Template.FindName(), so your problem is elsewhere. Did you try to call the method in the extension class of ContentControl?

Comment: Check out my small example to see my problem.  If you like :) http://www.vbninja.com/XAMLGridError.zip

Comment: I checked it out, the problem is that you extend the ListBox not the ContentControl. So for example if you try to get the "cc" ContentControl in the OnApplyTemplate() method which you set up it will duly return the ContentControl template part. Just extend ContentControl to get to your Grid inside!